# Why does $2^{\log\left(n\right)\left(\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)} = n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

**There are a few ways** to simplify the expression:
$\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}$

Edit: **The Log is BASE 2.**

One way, would be using the rule $a^{\log\left(b\right)}=b^{\log\left(a\right)}$

So, we would have the equation $\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}=\:n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}\:$

But there is another way that I didn't really understand.

---

We will append a log to this expression $\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}$,
so it will be $\log\left(\log\left(n\right)^{\log\left(n\right)}\right)$

according to the rule $\log(a)^b = b\log(a)$

it is going to be $\log(n)(\log(\log(n)))$

We are going to do the opposite of the $\log$ operation, and make it an exponent for the base 2:

$2^{\log\left(n\right)\left(\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)}$

The step I didn't understand is.. why does $2^{\log\left(n\right)\left(\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)\right)} = n^{\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}$ ?

---

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It holds only if $\log$ means $\log_2,$ which is relatively unsual.

Comment: @AnneBauval It is not unusual at all in any computer science/algorithms class or context :)

Comment: I know, whence my *relatively*. @ClementC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you reach the point where you got
$$
(\log n)^{\log n} = 2^{\log(n)\cdot \log\log n}
$$
(again, $\log$ here is base $2$).

Now, all you need to remember is that **(1)** $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ and **(2)** $2^{\log a} = a$ (for $a>0$), so
$$
(\log n)^{\log n} = 2^{\log(n)\cdot \log\log n} =
\left(2^{\log(n)}\right)^{\log\log n} = \boxed{n^{\log\log n}}
$$

Comment: It was a duplicate. Found using approach0: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%242%5E%7B%5Clog%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%5Cleft(%5Clog%5Cleft(%5Clog%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%20%3D%20n%5E%7B%5Clog%5Cleft(%5Clog%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%5Cright)%7D%24&p=1